# MySQL correlated subqueries with aliases

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

Hello i don't understant how correlated subqueries work under the hood. I have two tables an i want to check if two values are equal if some value of second one if some value from first table is equal to value from second table.
My code to do that is:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary 
FROM employees 
WHERE employees.salary = (SELECT min_salary
FROM jobs
WHERE employees.job_id = jobs.job_id);
```

How does it exactly work that it knows if the job_id is correct for employees Object when it comes to comparing salary in outer query?
Is it iterating over every value and its passing the value to alias.Object?

Let's say the value of the inner query is 2500. What if there is employee who earn 2500 but min_salary for his job_id would be 2000? How does this query knows when it's right or not?

If someone needs more details then everything is better explained here:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/subquery-exercises/find-the-names-salary-of-the-employees-whose-salary-is-equal-to-the-minimum-salary-for-their-job-grade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is executed once for each row in the table `employees`.

> What if there is employee who earn 2500 but min_salary for his job_id
> would be 2000?

For this case, the subquery:

```
SELECT min_salary FROM jobs WHERE employees.job_id = jobs.job_id
```

will return `2000` and the boolean expression in the `WHERE` clause will be `FALSE` because `2500 <> 2000` and that employee will be filtered out from the results.

The link between each row of `employees` and `jobs` is the columns `job_id`.

For each `job_id` in `employees` the table `jobs` is scanned again and again to fetch the corresponding `min_salary` and this value (which must be unique and I assume it is unique in a table called `jobs`) is compared against the column `salary` of `employees`.

This query could also be implemented with an `INNER` join where I believe it is more clear what is going on:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary 
FROM employees e INNER JOIN jobs j
ON j.job_id = e.job_id AND j.min_salary = e.salary;
```

Since you mention aliases in your question, use them to qualify all columns, even if you know that for some columns there is no other column with the same name. Also use short aliases to make the code shorter and more readable.

Comment: So it set up values right when it is executed for each value? I mean that we obviously don't see that but the query is like 2500 = (SELECT...) and then it's searching for corresponding value in subquery for that record which salary is already set as first part of WHERE statement? So it will be like you said 2500 = 2000 which is false. Do i get it right?

Comment: @jokonoo yes. this is how it works, for every row of employees.